# How do I reverse a map with a Set<Integer> included?

Tags: java

For instance if I have a map with integer and strings:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

This map would contain key values of Integers and values of names.
What I am trying to do is make a new map, that copies all the values (names) from theMap and makes them the keys for the new map.
 Now the tricky part I can't get, is that I want the values of the new map to be the numbers, but if there are multiple numbers that correspond to the same name 
I want them to be held in an Set.
Example of new map:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> returnMap = new TreeMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

So if "John" corresponds to 1,2,3,4. I would like the new map to contain a key of "John" with a Set containing 1,2,3,4

Comment: @AdrianShum You're right, I see that now.  Since each key is by definition unique, then as values they can't collide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that tricky :)

```
Map<Integer, String> map = ... //Your map
Map<String, Set<Integer>> reverseMap = new TreeMap<String, Set<Integer>>();

for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    Set<Integer> set;

    if(reverseMap.containsKey(value)) {
        set = reverseMap.get(value);
        set.add(key);
    } else {
        set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set.add(key);
        reverseMap.put(value, set);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer can be improved in several aspects: 1. It is meaningless to pull the `set` variable out.  Either you `if (contains) { set = map.get(v);} else { set = new HashSet; map.put(v, set); }  set.add(key);` or simply `if(contains){map.get(v).add(key);}else{set = new HashSet;....}`.  2. If OP is using Java8, the even more preferrable way is to use `Map.compute()`

Answer (score 5):

Google's [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) has a nice [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) class which maps keys to multiple values. If you use it, you can take advantage of a host of helper methods:

```
SetMultimap<String, Integer> returnMap =
    Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(myMap), TreeMultimap.create());
```